# How to customize django form label

Tags: django, forms, label, customization

```
class permForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, data=None, **kwargs):
        super(permForm, self).__init__(data, **kwargs)

        for item in list(AdminMenu.objects.filter(parent_id=0)):
            self.fields['menu_%d' % item.id] = forms.BooleanField(label=item.title)
            for childitem in list(AdminMenu.objects.filter(parent_id=item.id)):
                arr=[]
                arr.append(str(item.id))
                arr.append(str(childitem.id))
                self.fields['menu_%s' % '_'.join(arr)] = forms.BooleanField(label=childitem.title)
```

This will return

category: checkbox

add category: checkbox

List Category:checkbox

Food: checkbox

Add Fooditems: checkbox

List Fooditem: checkbox

Tables: checkbox

Add Tables: checkbox

List Tables: checkbox

Users: checkbox

View Users: checkbox

How can i display it as following

**category:** checkbox

add category: checkbox

List Category:checkbox

**Food**: checkbox

Add Fooditems: checkbox

List Fooditem: checkbox

**Tables**: checkbox

Add Tables: checkbox

List Tables: checkbox

**Users**: checkbox

View Users: checkbox

I WANT TO MAKE PARENT CATEGORY LABEL BOLD TO DISTINGUISH IT FROM CHILD. POSSIBLE?
I DONT WANT TO USE HARD CODED FORMS

Comment: use CSS, it is much simpler and easier to change. Your form label will never change if you don't change the the django form model.

Comment: No need to yell. As @platinummonkey suggested, you can always use CSS, short of that your only choice is to render each field individually in your form and add whatever extra tags you want that way. You *cannot* include HTML in a label in Django.

Comment: Actually, you can. See my answer for example code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's an example of how to add some HTML to form labels:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import mark_safe


class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_field = forms.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        label = mark_safe('<strong>My Bold Field Label</strong>')
    )
```

Comment: Very nice but a little dirty.

Comment: A cleaner approach would probably be to put the label text into a template and use render_to_string, thus not polluting the Python code with HTML.

Comment: Maybe the solution would be to use floppyforms to extends the label form rendering for this field.

Comment: If you need to swat a fly with a cannon, then yes :)